# Why is the completion event stopping this test from passing?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I realize there is a lot of code here for a SO question, but it's the best I can do at the moment... You can just copy/paste the code into an rx-enabled playground to see the problem.

On line 89 there is a commented out piece of code `let creds = Observable.just(credentials)//.concat(Observable.never())`. If I remove the `//` and allow the concat, the code will pass its test. Can anybody give a clue as to why this code fails the test if `creds` is allowed to send a completion event?

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import UIKit

typealias Credentials = (email: String, password: String)

struct User {
    let id: String
    let properties: [Property]
}

struct Property {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct LoginParams {
    let touchIDPossible: Bool
}

class LoginScreen {
    var attemptLogin: Observable<Credentials> {
        assert(_attemptLogin == nil)
        _attemptLogin = PublishSubject()
        return _attemptLogin!
    }

    var _attemptLogin: PublishSubject<(email: String, password: String)>?
}

class DashboardScreen {
    func display(property: Observable<Property?>) {
        property.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            self._property = $0
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }

    var _property: Property?
    let bag = DisposeBag()
}

class Interface {
    func login(params: LoginParams) -> Observable<LoginScreen> {
        assert(_login == nil)
        _login = PublishSubject()
        return _login!
    }

    func dashboard() -> Observable<DashboardScreen> {
        assert(_dashboard == nil)
        _dashboard = PublishSubject()
        return _dashboard!
    }

    var _login: PublishSubject<LoginScreen>?
    var _dashboard: PublishSubject<DashboardScreen>?
    let bag = DisposeBag()
}

class Server {
    func user(credentials: Credentials) -> Observable<User> {
        assert(_user == nil)
        _user = PublishSubject()
        return _user!
    }

    func property(id: String) -> Observable<Property> {
        assert(_property == nil)
        _property = PublishSubject()
        return _property!
    }

    var _user: PublishSubject<User>?
    var _property: PublishSubject<Property>?
}

class Coordinator {

    init(interface: Interface, server: Server) {
        self.interface = interface
        self.server = server
    }

    func start() {
        let credentials = (email: "foo", password: "bar")

        // remove the `//` and the test will pass. Why does it fail when `creds` completes?
        let creds = Observable.just(credentials)//.concat(Observable.never())

        let autoUser = creds.flatMap {
            self.server.user(credentials: $0)
                .materialize()
                .filter { !$0.isCompleted }
            }.shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        let login = autoUser.filter { $0.error != nil }
            .flatMap { _ in self.interface.login(params: LoginParams(touchIDPossible: false)) }

        let attempt = login.flatMap { $0.attemptLogin }
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        let user = attempt.flatMap {
            self.server.user(credentials: $0)
                .materialize()
                .filter { !$0.isCompleted }
            }.shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        let propertyID = Observable.merge(autoUser, user).map { $0.element }
            .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
            .map { $0.properties.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name }).map({ $0.id }).first }

        let property = propertyID.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
            .flatMap { self.server.property(id: $0)
                .map { Optional.some($0) }
                .catchErrorJustReturn(nil)
            }.debug("property").shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        let dashboard = property.flatMap { _ in self.interface.dashboard() }

        dashboard.map { $0.display(property: property) }
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    let interface: Interface
    let server: Server
    let bag = DisposeBag()
}

do {
    let interface = Interface()
    let server = Server()
    let coordinator = Coordinator(interface: interface, server: server)

    coordinator.start()

    assert(server._user != nil)

    let simpleProperty = Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")
    let user = User(id: "foo", properties: [simpleProperty])
    server._user?.onNext(user)
    server._user?.onCompleted()
    server._user = nil

    assert(interface._login == nil)

    assert(server._property != nil)

    let property = Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")
    server._property!.onNext(property)
    server._property!.onCompleted()
    server._property = nil

    assert(interface._dashboard != nil)

    let dashboard = DashboardScreen()
    interface._dashboard?.onNext(dashboard)
    interface._dashboard?.onCompleted()

    assert(dashboard._property != nil)
    print("test passed")
}
```

Here is the output of the code as it is above:

```
2017-06-01 22:22:42.534: property -> subscribed
2017-06-01 22:22:42.552: property -> Event next(Optional(__lldb_expr_134.Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")))
2017-06-01 22:22:42.557: property -> Event completed
2017-06-01 22:22:42.557: property -> isDisposed
2017-06-01 22:22:42.559: property -> subscribed
assertion failed: file MyPlayground.playground, line 159
```

Why is the `property` being subscribed to *after* it has been disposed?

Here is the output if you remove the `\\`:

```
2017-06-01 22:23:51.540: property -> subscribed
2017-06-01 22:23:51.553: property -> Event next(Optional(__lldb_expr_136.Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")))
test passed
```

Comment: Since we don't have your line numbers, can you at least add a comment to the code about which assertion fails (on line 159)?

Comment: Sorry, it is the last assert that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I originally suggested keeping the `dashboard` around in a DisposeBag so that when `start()` completes, the reference doesn't go away too early. The OP has since updated the code, so here's an updated attempt at an answer.*

---

When you add more debug information:

```
let dashboard = property.debug("prop in")
    .flatMap { _ in self.interface.dashboard().debug("dash in") }
    .debug("dash out")
```

The log will reveal that the property completes early, namely right after the inner sequence has been subscribed to ("dash in -> subscribed"):

```
2017-06-03 08:33:27.442: property -> Event next(Optional(Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")))
2017-06-03 08:33:27.442: prop in -> Event next(Optional(Property(id: "bar", name: "tampa")))
2017-06-03 08:33:27.449: dash in -> subscribed
2017-06-03 08:33:27.452: property -> Event completed
2017-06-03 08:33:27.452: property -> isDisposed
2017-06-03 08:33:27.452: prop in -> Event completed
2017-06-03 08:33:27.452: prop in -> isDisposed
2017-06-03 08:33:27.456: dash in -> Event next(DashboardScreen)
2017-06-03 08:33:27.456: dash out -> Event next(DashboardScreen)
```

If you `.concat(.never())`, the completion event is not fired and does not interfere with the process.

The problem is your test code is written imperatively. You `start()` the process and then publish changes. But the whole thing falls apart even sooner if you put the various `onNext` events onto the main queue asynchronously. Your Coordinator's design reads like declarative code, but is really used like a fancy imperative sequential code path.

A remedy is to factor timeliness in. `PublishSubjects` have no history; if you use `BehaviorSubjects` that replay their latest value instead, you can set up all changes *before* calling `start()` and it'll work. I assume you use `PublishSubject`s because you call `start()` first to open the pipe and want to push changes through it one after another. Problem is, your pipe is made in a way that doesn't wait for you to push everything through. The input valve closes independently, so to speak.

Yeah, this metaphor was not the best in all human history :)

So the options really are:

1. Make all of the Coordinator's work a big `Observable.combineLatest` so that the whole transformation sequence isn't started until every sequence had their say,
2. use buffering/replaying subjects and set them up in advance,
3. replace the `.just` (which completes) with a base sequence that never completes to keep the pipeline open; you can make this an `Observable<Observable<Credentials>>` where the outer sequence stays alive and the inner sequences uses `Observable.just` -- though I doubt your production code will depend on this little detail at all.

Comment: Adding the DisposeBag didn't help, the assert still fires. Either there is something special about the completion event that I don't understand, or there is a bug in RxSwift.